# Set of modular equations in Wolfram|Alpha

Tags: modular-arithmetic, wolfram-alpha

Am I able to solve set of modular equations in Wolfram|Alpha, like for example:

$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x \equiv 2 \pmod{3} \\
x \equiv 3 \pmod{5}
\end{matrix}\right.
$

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to type :

$x ~\text {mod}~ 3 = 2~,~x ~\text {mod}~ 5 = 3$

WolframAlpha [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+mod+3+%3D+2,+x+mod+5+%3D+3)