# How can I solve system of linear equations over finite fields in WolframAlpha?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, wolfram-alpha

Is it possible to solve system of linear equations over finite fields using Wolfram Alpha? If yes, how can I do that?

Let us take a system $x+y+z=0$, $2x+y+2z=0$, $x+3y+z=0$.

If I want to solve this linear system over $\mathbb Z_7=\mathbb Z/(7)$, one thing I can do is to type
`(x+y+z) mod 7=0, (2x+y+2z) mod 7=0, (x+3y+z) mod 7=0`
into WA, here is [a link](http://tinyurl.com/o3mgaqv). (This approach was suggested in an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112837/set-of-modular-equations-in-wolframalpha).)

WA can solve this, but a solution is given by enumerating the residue classes. I would prefer some more compact notation, for example something similar like what WA does for the same [system over real numbers](http://tinyurl.com/ow8uef9), i.e., when I type `x+y+z=0, 2x+y+2z=0, x+3y+z=0` into WA. (Getting a basis for a solution space would be nice, but even expression in the form given in this case seems somehow better than listing all residue classes.)

- Would I be able to solve system linear equations over finite fields $G(p^n)$? (For example if I chose the representation $GF(4)=\mathbb Z_2/(x^2+x+1)$ and tried to solve the above system in this field?)
- Is it possible to obtain some kind of more compact notation at least in the case of fields of the form $\mathbb Z_p=\mathbb Z/(p)$ (where $p$ is some prime number)?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, I'll mention in a comment that according to [this meta discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/are-questions-related-to-using-wolfram-alpha-on-topic), questions about WA are on-topic on this site.

Comment: There is a [finite fields package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/FiniteFields/guide/FiniteFieldsPackage.html) for Mathematica. I don't know if it can be accessed in WA. You need to overload the field arithmetic operations for the package to work.

Comment: +1 I'm often frustrated by the differences between Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica; interested in seeing how the former can be coaxed to do this